# How to safely change grub2 screen resolution?

Tags: grub2, screen, display-resolution

`grub2` isn't really fit in the best screen resolution that my laptop can support (1280 x 800).

How can I do this without using a third party application ?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To do this safely requires two steps.

### Step 1: find the preferred mode

Reboot and press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to display your grub.  Press `C` to enter console mode. Then type (for Ubuntu versions before 18.04):

```
$ vbeinfo
```

For Ubuntu 18.04 and later:

```
$ videoinfo
```

This will display various stuff how grub recognizes your display.  At the bottom is "preferred mode" - in your case it should say 1280x800.  Note down the value.

***Note:*** sometimes, some buggy video cards incorrectly give Grub the wrong preferred resolution - if the preferred mode is much higher than you were expecting, then select the nearest mode in the list displayed that you were expecting.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to grub and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot.

### Step 2: Setting the resolution in grub

Reach for your terminal and type

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find the line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

remove the `#` and change `640x480` with the preferred mode you wrote down. E.g.:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800
```

save, then type

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

***Note:*** the preferred mode has to be among those listed by vbeinfo.  For example, if your preferred mode is 1920x1080 (a common 16x9 aspect ratio setting), your preferred mode is NOT supported by vbeinfo and may not work correctly.  In fact, there do not seem to be any 16x9 modes supported by vbeinfo, as of Ubuntu 13.04. In that case you could try falling back to something common like 640x480, which, it seems most monitors support and vbeinfo supports.  Also, not all the modes supported by vbeinfo are necessarily supported by your monitor and you may have to experiment.

Comment: @fossfreedom: I dont see anything when the grub is shown, my screen says "Out of range signal". Thus I cannot see the output of `vbeinfo`. How do I rectify in that case ?

Comment: @user01 - you'll need to first boot into ubuntu - set the GRUB_GFXMODE in grub to something low like 640x480.  Then the next reboot you'll have grub and you can then see the output of vbeinfo

Comment: You can use `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` shows the same information as vbeinfo.

Comment: While running 16.0.4 I noticed that the resolution kept getting reset after the kernel started. I had to add:  GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep" and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset" to make it stick.

Comment: That fixed grub, but to fix the TTY console resolution I needed to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` and selected terminus 16x32 for the font. (Note that nomodeset caused a worse problem. Other details: Ubuntu 18.04, Dell XPS 15, 3840 x 2160).

Comment: Note under a 16.04 recent install `vbeinfo` isn't found but rather `videoinfo` which your answer links to 18.04 is found: `Jan 25 03:50  /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/videoinfo.mod` +1 though and thanks for updating your answer 7 years later.

Comment: `videoinfo` only shows one resolution--2880x1800, which makes everything really tiny. Is there a way to change to a resolution not listed in `videoinfo`?

Comment: Mentioned above: `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` does NOT show the same information as videoinfo during boot. I believe one is showing resolutions after my NVIDIA drivers are loaded and the other is before.

Comment: videoinfo: command not found and vbeinfo: command not found

Comment: This made literally no difference *whatsoever* to the size of the font or the console screen resolution it's still tiny AF.

Comment: Note that to get the  result from vbeinfo or videoinfo, the bios secuity must be disabled.

Answer (score 37):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and things are a little different in the packaged version of Grub for me.

The `vbeinfo` command does not exist.

1. Turn on
2. At the grub menu press <kbd>c</kbd> to get the grub comand line
3. Type `videoinfo`
   This lists all the modes - it is the <width>x<height> you need to make note of.
4. Optionally, there is a `videotest` command which you can use to test a given resolution, e.g. `videotest 1280x1024`.  **However**, while this test worked for me, I could not then get back to the grub menu!  So that's not quite as useful (unless anyone can explain how to escape the test.)
5. Boot up fully and edit (sudo) `/etc/default/grub` but the line you're looking for is now called `GRUB_GFXMODE`. So un-comment and set that to your desired mode.
6. Run `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: For me with 16.04, typing `videoinfo` at the grub command-line resulted in an error like "Secure Boot forbids loading module...". So then I disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS settings and then a more reasonable screen resolution appeared in the grub menu without me having to do anything else. Maybe the Secure Boot option was stopping grub's default `auto` value for `GRUB_GFXMODE` from taking effect.

Comment: 'hwinfo --framebuffer' at bash command line is supposed to be the same thing as 'vbeinfo' or 'videoinfo', but it doesn't work for me.  (I get one line after another output to screen, but every line overwrites the previous, and the last line is erased by bash prompt.  Redirecting output to file yields an empty file.)

Comment: To exit `videotest`, I just use CTRL+ALT+DELETE to restart grub.

Answer (score 9):

I am running 14.04LTS on an ASUS M51AC with an Nvidia 625GT OEM. I found that in addition to the accepted answer, I needed to also add the line:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep"
```

to /etc/default/grub.

Comment: https://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/

Comment: Holy shit this finally solved a seemingly completely unrelated issue: After changing monitors from 1920x1080 to 1920x1200, GRUB was displayed in a very low resolution, and after booting Ubuntu, the screen would go into power save mode, sometimes taking a minute or so to come back. With the right resolution and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep"`, it finally starts up as desired!

Answer (score 9):

For me on Ubuntu 17.10 server it was

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080x32"
```

I also had to set the following to prevent shutdown from hanging

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Grub Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183#post10340183):

Easy to use Grub2 settings customizer.  Go to "Preferences" -> "Appearance"

- check "custom resolution" and select one of the available resolution
- click "close"
- hit "save"
- close program and restart computer

[image]

Comment: i've found this method to be unreliable, my menu colors never update and the resolution list is not valid in all cases. luckily nothing breaks when choosing an unsupported resolution, it just doesn't change anything

Comment: I used to have the same issue where no visual settings applied would take hold... under the "Advanced" tab in "Preference" make sure "GRUB_GFXMODE" is checked and when using a background picture make sure it is in the same "/boot" folder as the grub installation.  Now all options w/in the program works perfectly for me w/ no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS this worked for me (on ESXi VMs):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

make sure to remove `maybe-ubiquity`

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

make sure to comment/disable this line.

```
GFX_GFXMODE=1024x768 
GFX_PAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
```

change to desired resolution