# After installing Ubuntu my screen's frequency is out of range when I boot to Windows

Tags: 11.10, windows-vista

Okay so I have Vista Home Basic 32 bit, and had recently installed Ubuntu 11.10, but I discovered when I tried to boot onto Vista, it said "Out of Range", I know that the message is talking about refresh rate or resolution and I am sure I have the same resolution in Ubuntu as Vista.

I'm pretty sure my refresh rate is 60hz, but the out of range message says:

```
V=somethingKhz
H=58Hz
MAX=1280x1024(current and same resolution on both boots)
```

1 last thing: I can't get into F8 boot menu for Windows. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution), basically:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

to something like

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
```

That resolution might work. Finally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay what I did to solve the problem was installing boot-manager. 
This link will provide you with the instructions to help eliminate this issue! 
I run a rig with an Nvidia Pony 7900 GTX 528 mb ram and the monitor is a cheap Hyundai 
Model #: x93s

No actual drivers really for this monitor, even on win 7 I had to get a driver with a different prefix like k93s or something to that effect.

Boot-Manager will allow you to configure the resolution and bits.

Worked wonder for me so I recommend this if you want to eliminate the problem.

Link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto

-Peace, 
***Lorenzo***

PS. I exhausted the grub edit method, did not work at all for me! I think it is also Video card specific, and also what kind of connection, such as VGA or DVI. Just an after thought!