# Dual boot stuck on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I recently dual booted my old Windows xp with Ubuntu 12 using the iso burned to a CD (wubi).  The installation worked like a dream but after rebooting I found there was no way of getting back to XP.  After restarting the screen simply says "out of range" (meaning what?) and anything from 10-30 seconds later goes straight to the linux login page.  The bizarre thing is I can still access the Windows drive from inside Ubuntu, but any Microsoft/Windows specific products won't open.  I'm not sure Grub is working properly either.  Ubuntu is great to have but I wanted the choice on booting up, not being locked out Windows as this machine is.

Please advise.

Comment: Please indicate if you installed Ubuntu by booting from the CD and choosing to install Ubuntu side by side to Windows, or did you run the WUBI from within Windows? If you installed by booting from the CD, See [this question about screen resolution our of range](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185502/screen-resolution-out-of-range)

Comment: The CD opened inside windows initially and on rebooting it gave a choice of windows/ubuntu, leading to the full installation in the linux system choosing side by side (partitioned 300GB windows, 200GB ubuntu).  The fact the windows files are there suggests they have not been overwritten.

Comment: This question has been answered before. Please see the link above.

Comment: I have gone through the commands in the above links and changed the resolution in grub.  My next headache is when I try to run sudo-update grub I get

"Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
/etc/default/grub: line 35: x: command not found" 

so I assume it is not being updated.  Problems like this have probably been answered but I haven't found this.

Comment: Could you use `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` to open `/etc/default/grub` and **copy line 35 in the question above**? It looks like you may have put something in that line, that does not belong there. **Always edit your original question with additional information** This helps others understand the question and answer without going through the comments. Thanks.

Comment: By sheer luck I landed on grub-customizer, and changed the resolution to the lowest available just to be sure and it worked.  I had previously changed resolution via the terminal to 1024-768 but my monitor is not that at all, closer to 800x600.  This can be marked solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71643/after-installing-ubuntu-my-screens-frequency-is-out-of-range-when-i-boot-to-win) is a similar issue. Try to check you `grub` settings as described by link.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the links, it appeared similar questions had been asked but wasn't sure if precisely the same issue was discussed.  Incidently I went through the Grub console update in the above link and after sudo update it said "line 35: x command not found"