# GRUB2: Use maximum detected resolution?

Tags: boot, grub2, resolution

How do I tell GRUB2 to set its resolution (and also the one passed to the kernel) to the maximum one it can **detect at time of boot**?

Comment: [This answer should answer your question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)

Comment: @severin: No, it doesn't. That only tells me how to set it to a *specific* resolution that *I* can find, not to ***the maximum one it detects at boot time***.

Comment: ´vbeinfo´ will tell you the maximum supported resolution. Then you can edit /etc/default/grub to use that resolution.

Comment: @severin: You're *still* not understanding the question!! :( 
 I want **automatic** detection, not *manual* detection.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Do you have like, variable resolutions?

Comment: @AmithKK: Uh, yes? I have variable resolutions...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I presume the reason you are asking about this is that you use different monitors on the same Ubuntu machine and you want GRUB2 to look good on all of them. However, if you are concerned about the resolution used once Ubuntu boots, this *does not address that*. GRUB2 does not "pass on to the kernel" the resolution it selects for the boot menu.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` as `root`. You may want to back it up first:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old
```

(You would run that in the Terminal, which you can open by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.)

To edit it with Gedit as `root` run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

(Or if you're using Kubuntu, run `kdesudo kate /etc/default/grub` instead.)

You'll get a lot of messages in the Terminal, if you run that command in the Terminal rather than with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. You'll notice they don't say they pertain to the file you're editing, so that's fine.

You'll find that part of the file says something like this:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Uncomment (i.e., remove the leading `#` from) the line that says `GRUB_GFXMODE`, and change the resolution from `640x480` to `auto`. The line should now read:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto
```

Save the file and quit the editor. In the Terminal, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

(This must be run after every modification to `/etc/default/grub`, to apply the changes.)

Now reboot, and see if that does what you want.

It might not (as it uses the "platform default" which might not be the highest possible). If that is the case, edit `/etc/default/grub` again, and this time change the line so it says something like:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1600x1200,1280x1024,1024x768,800x600,640x480
```

You will not necessarily want to use exactly that line. You should list all the resolutions you want to be tried, in the order you want them to be tried. The resolutions I have listed are the most standard resolutions for monitors with a 4:3 aspect ratio, but widescreen monitors (including most laptop screens these days) have different form factors and use different resolutions. Wikipedia has a [list of common resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions) which may help you. If you know the specific resolutions you want for each device, you can just list them (highest first). You should probably include `640x480` or `auto` at the end . I recommend this because I don't know if GRUB2 will always try a safe low resolution, if you don't include that.

Then save the file again, run `sudo update-grub` again, reboot again, and see if that does what you need.

If it doesn't, you may be out of luck. GRUB2 doesn't display video the same way as Ubuntu does once it's booted. GRUB2 uses [VESA BIOS Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions) to display the boot menu with enhanced resolution (and color depth), and a machine's maximum resolution through VBE is not always as high as the maximum resolution supported by the video card and monitor.

**Source:** The [official GRUB2 documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#gfxmode). (You'll notice [the version number is 1.99](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2). It's still GRUB2. A bit confusing, but true.)

*[Finally, thanks to [TechZilla](https://askubuntu.com/users/34219/techzilla) for pointing out a serious error in the original version of this answer.]*

Comment: +1 definitely a viable solution, even though it's not perfect. Thanks for the detailed answer, it's very well-written!

Comment: Also just an FYI, `GRUB_GFXMODE=auto` nearly always gets the best resolution possible via VESA. The VESA widescreen resolutions are not standardized, and I have never once been able to get one working from Grub2.  I have heard it's possible, if using an Intel GFX chip and some semi-complicated VESA soft-patching.  AFAIK this is not possible with non-Intel GFX chips. ... also you should add a +1 to my comment if it was on target. :P

Comment: @Mehrdad Give the bounty to this answer. This is as close as your going to get AFAIK :D

Comment: @AmithKK: I most likely will, though I think I'll just wait a little and let other people get a chance to at least read the question before I award it haha. :)

Answer (score 12):

There's also a GUI option available.

**Grub Customizer:**

Grub Customizer allows to edit, rename, re-order or freeze Grub entries. It also allows to change the background colors of Grub menu or add a custom picture and supports BURG customization also. You can also use Grub Customizer from a Live CD/USB environment to fix your boot issues.

**Installation:**

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

**How to use:**

Once installed, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `grub-customizer` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Authenticate by giving your user password.

Once open, click on `Preferences` in toolbar.

[image]

Under `Appearance` tab enable `custom resolution`, and type `auto` in the text box.

[image]

Alternatively under `Advanced` tab enable `GRUB_GFXMODE` and type `auto` in the text field in front of it. You can also specify resolution as a sequence of one or more modes, separated by commas (‘,’) or semicolons (‘;’); each will be tried in turn until one is found. For example:

`1440x900,1680x1050,1920x1200,2560x1600`

Or specified with depth (8, 16 or 24):

`1440x900x16,1680x1050x16,1920x1200x16,2560x1600x16`

[image]

Close the `Preferences` dialog box and click save on the toolbar of main window. That's it!

[image]

*To remove Grub Customizer run following commands in terminal:*

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge grub-customizer
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
```