# How to change TTY resolution after boot?

Tags: resolution, tty

How do I change the TTY resolution after the system has already booted?

Comment: Does this relate to your question about [automatically selecting the resolution used by GRUB2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103516/grub2-use-maximum-detected-resolution)? Because the virtual console framebuffer resolution (for tty1, tty2, and so forth) is not related to the GRUB2 resolution (though they might both turn out the same). And do you need to set this once you have booted, or just have the option to set it *as* you are booting?

Comment: @EliahKagan: Yeah I know they're not related, or I wouldn't have asked it separately. :) It's a different question. And no, I meant exactly what I wrote: I want to change it **after** booting.

Answer (score 0):

«… If one does wish to use and explore the framebuffer, the 'fbset' command allows one to change several settings of the framebuffer on the fly. `sudo apt-get install fbset`[image: Install stackapplet] […»](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer)

Comment: I get this error when using `fbset`: `open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory`

Comment: So you need framebuffer driver loaded, don't you?

Comment: I do, but how do I load it?

Comment: Find out model of your video cards and use `modprbe` appropriately.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... how do I use `modprobe` "appropriately"? What parameters do I give it?

Comment: Params are driver dependent actually. `man fbset` mentions `/usr/share/doc/fbset/` — haven't you tried studying the directory content?