# How do you resize the standard Ubuntu Desktop inside of Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

So I've installed Ubuntu inside of Virtualbox, and I resized the window of Virtualbox to be full-size, but the Ubuntu Desktop stays the same standard size. How do I make the width of Ubuntu stretch 100% across the Virtualbox window?

Comment: If you don't have X (i.e. you only installed server) and don't want to install it, you need to change the resolution for grub - see those instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/q/54067/247661

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Inside the virtual machine, install the `virtualbox-guest-dkms`, `virtualbox-guest-utils` and `virtualbox-guest-x11` packages. These "guest additions" include a video driver that will do what you ask, plus a mouse driver that interacts with the host system so you don't have to use the host key to "uncapture" the mouse; it just works when you're on the virtual machine's window.

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. From the VirtualBox top menu choose *Devices*, *Install guest additions*, then wait for a mock-CD ROM to appear and run the install from there, or
2. just type

   `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11`

(personal recommendation: the second (apt-get) option is very simple and quick).

Comment: Fantastic. I was in the process of installing the Guest Additions via the link in Virtualbox when you wrote this. However, I believe I watched as those packages were installed as well. I appreciate your help.

Comment: +1 - thanks! It seems that just `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms` is required as that automatically installs the utils and x11 packages.

Comment: This tip is really helpful. On 14.04 trusty fails to load screen vbox screen resolutions. Installing the applets fixes the bug and the X server behaves like XP inside virtualbox.

Comment: Also note you have to give enough video RAM (more than 17 MB) to have this work

Comment: Also note that, as of the newer versions (14.04), ubuntu supports mouse and keyboard capture without any guest additions. But display is still in question.

Comment: Even though your answer is OLD, it still works to fix the resolution problem TODAY.... I have tried all the other options suggested by others in here and on the Internet and did not work at all... Thank you so much.......

Comment: Tried solution #2 with Ubuntu 14.04 running on top of OSX 10.10. The install of virtualbox-guest-x11 using `apt-get` failed with unmet dependencies.  Using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` installed the package, but removed a bunch of files so that the desktop no longer appears.

Comment: With 14.04 also, I ran the apt-get and already had the updates. Then went in to "System Settings"->"Displays" and selected the resolution there. Now resizing works - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Shutdown your virtual box and in a terminal shell type the following command

VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution 1366,768

the 1366,768 is just what i have set for my screen resolution on my laptop, change this to whatever your current resolution is on the machine your running.  This should maximize all screens to full 100% on all guest os's

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I like learning different ways to do things.

Comment: I tried everything else, no luck. But this answer worked perfect. Nice answer :) TX :)

Comment: Just to add value to this answer, if you are using Vagrant, instead of the using the setextradata VBoxManage command, you can indirectly call it from the Vagrant file like so (see the second vb.customize):

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = true
        vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "GUI\/LastGuestSizeHint", "1920,1080"]
    end

Answer (score 4):

Once you have installed the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (scroll until you see the Extension Pack section) use <kbd>host</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or the menu option under <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Auto-resize Guest Display</kbd>.

> <sup>*NOTE: The Extension Pack version must match the version of VirtualBox.*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Using Ubuntu inside VirtualBox on Win7 you need to reboot Ubuntu after the `virtualbox-guest-dkms` install before resizing would work.

Comment: Actually, the guest additions installer itself ask the user to reboot, no matter what host is involved. Without rebooting the screen won't re-size.

Comment: I wasn't asked to reboot after installing guest additions via apt-get. Couldn't resize to full screen until I rebooted the guest system. +1 (host: Win 7; guest: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: Same here. Wouldn't resize before a reboot.

Comment: FYI: as of 18.04.2 LTS, I was not asked to reboot.