# Ubuntu VM won't respond after recent window resizing

Tags: virtualbox

I couldn't resize the window of the VM so I looked-up solutions online. One solution was to install 3 pkgs that are aimed towards the guest OS (Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS - Desktop). The solution worked: [How do you resize the standard Ubuntu Desktop inside of Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104440/how-do-you-resize-the-standard-ubuntu-desktop-inside-of-virtualbox)
. When I view the login screen, everything is normal, I can use my mouse and keyboard, open new ttys, etc, but, after logging in, I can't do anything, the machine won't respond to my inputs but it is responsive (the time is changing, wallpapers are changing, etc). What can I do to fix this? I'm running windows10 and I use Oracle VMBox version 6.

Thank you for your time and help, Anthon.

Comment: Installing `Guest Additions` would have/should have been enough. What exact version VB? How can you "open new ttys" if you haven't logged in? In VB, is your mouse/keyboard captured? Check the small icons at the bottom of the VB window.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. Before logging via the GDM session, I can switch to other ttys. I did notice the small icons. Before logging in, they are fine but after logging in, I think that the mouse wasn't blinking. I am running the latest version.

Comment: Click, or right-click, on the keyboard/mouse icons, and if I recall, it'll pop up a menu where you can select an action.