# How to newly install Ubuntu 16.04 with GTX 1080

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

My machine is

- Acer Aspire with Nvidia GTX 1080
- Dell E1910 monitor
- Window 10 is currently installed

I now want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my machine and started to install using a CD. This error message is shown:

> The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display.
>   Please change your input timing to 1440x900@60GHz or any other monitor
>   listed timing as per the monitor specifications.

I have tried selecting `nomodeset` on boot and enter install Ubuntu. 
But I can't still install Ubuntu and I need somebody help me with this.

Comment: From a grub command line to see available settings pressing <c> & then escape to get back to menu
`vbeinfo` to see supported mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution  Also with Acer you have to after install, set UEFI password & enable trust from inside UEFI on grub/ubuntu UEFI boot files.